# What accessories are needed to connect my iphone 5 with iPad Mini?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm looking to connect my iPhone 5 to my iPad Mini to upload pictures taken from my iPhone 5. What adapters and/or cables are needed?

---

Update: According to [this article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-manage-your-photos-when-traveling-with-an-iphone-and-ipad), it is possible. Has something changed in the iOS to not allow this?

Comment: This is not possible. There exists no way to tether two Apple mobile devices together because the operating system does not support this functionality. As suggested below by @onik, you should look to wireless solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A wireless recommendation would be to use iCloud to sync the photos between the devices. Just go to Settings > iCloud > Photos and turn on Photo Stream. After this, all new photos will be synced to the cloud and back to all devices that use the same iCloud account.

You could also install Dropbox and sync the photos from there. Or use Flicr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lightning to USB camera adapter. This seems to be the new version of the iPad camera connector kit which worked perfectly on older non-lightning iPads.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD821ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter